# Breakpoints are not hit. I get "breakpoint will not be hit, the code source is different" message

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Working on an old ASP.Net project using VB. I am using VS2012.

The debugger does not handle my breakpoints for a specific class (no prob with other classes so far).

When I run the app without having changed the file, its breakpoints are correctly hit. If I change anything into this file (even adding a \n character), the next time I run the app, its breakpoints are not hit anymore and I can read under the breakpoint the usual warning saying that "breakpoints will not be hit because the source code is different".

How can I have the debugger to accept my changes into this file? Why is it only causing trouble with this specific file?

I tried to remove my ASP temporary files as suggested in other similar posts. Did not help.

Rebuilding does not help either.

Thx in advance

Comment: We had this not too long ago with a C# project, compiling the project seemed to fix the issue for the other user.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild solution

Comment: This is an ASP.NET project. There is no option to clean it.
Rebuilding it does not fix the issue.

Comment: I take it the classes that do work are setup in the same way as the class that doesn't? My first thought would be to recreate the class if that's an option.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a _file_ issue rather than a _class_ issue. Make sure that the files produced by the compiler are being written to the correct place. Or, to look at it from the other side, make sure that the files being executed are the ones produced by the last compile.

Comment: @ Jinx88909 : I have this issue into 2 projects. Re-creating the class worked for one of them. I still have the issue in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Right click on the break point->Location->Allow the source code to be different from the original version(Tick the check box).

Solution 2: If the above solution doesn't work goto Debug->Attach to process, then attach the port/ service in which your current web project runs.
Hope this helps.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, is there a way to turn on "allow the source code to be different from the original version" by default?
Rather than having to set it on every break you use

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that you currently have the Configuration Manager set to "Build" the ASP.NET project that you're making changes in. This is found under Build -> Configuration Manager.

Then rebuild the solution/project.